# Python 2.7 pady margin errors

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Assign different numbers for pady give me errors. I've tried many ways of doing this and none of them work. I always get errors. Maybe the code is wrong, I'm not sure what it should be. This is the best I can think it would be, but I'm getting errors without any explaining why.

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x300")
root.title("basicGUI")
root.configure(background="gray") 

w1=Label(text="widget 1",
         pady = (TOP = "20", BOTTOM = "1"))
w1.pack()

w2=Label(text="widget 2",
         pady = (TOP = "1", BOTTOM = "1"))
w2.pack()

w3=Label(text="widget 3",
         pady = (TOP = "1", BOTTOM = "20"))
w3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: please include the actual error in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice: answer replaces pack with grid. Label area is not where positional should go, in this instance. This code will not cause errors.

```
w1=Label(frame, text="widget 1")
w1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady =(20,1))

w2=Label(frame, text="widget 2")
w2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady =(1,1))

w3=Label(frame, text="widget 3")
w3.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = (1,20))
```

Comment: Billal BEGUERADJ, code works in all my .py programs. In Frame or not in Frame it gives no errors. It's a keeper. Thanks.
Bryan Oakley, your code only works out of Frame. In Frame it gives errors. Also I looked at your webSite suggestion. It's too cryptic for me. It's written for extreme experience, which I am not.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, you always give wonderful information, which helps me so much. I always look forward to see your answers. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have two or three problems, depending on how you count.

The `pady` option *in the label*`takes a single value. If you want to give it two values, use the`pady`attribute of the pack command. The`pady`option on the label itself has a different behavior than the`pady`option for the`pack` command.

The second problem is that the tkinter constant `TOP` has the value `"top"`, which means you're trying to create a tuple (illegally) as `("top"="20", "bottom"="1")`. As you can hopefully see, that is invalid syntax.

Here is the correct way to do what you want:

```
w1.pack(pady=(20, 10))
```

Comment: Good to know. I tried some tricks but did not work. I looked into `pack()` method also but could not find any information related to this.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: when I google "tkinter pack" the first link I get is this, which does a decent job of explaining all of the options: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm